# Apply wordstyles to insertedHTML in Aspose.Words for .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose.words

Good day, everyone.

How can I apply predefined styles of word document to inserted HTML?

Like:

```
builder.InsertHTML(post.Title)
// apply style from document "Media-title"
builder.InsertHTML(post.Content)
// apply style "Media-content"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note InsertHtml() overload with useBuilderFormatting will not override styles of HTML text having inline styles. You may implement INodeChangingCallback for applying styles/formatting to HTML text. Please check following code snippet for reference.

```
public static void HtmlFormatting() 
{
    // Create a blank document object
    Document doc = new Document();
    DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

    // Set up and pass the object which implements the handler methods.
    doc.NodeChangingCallback = new HandleNodeChanging_FontChanger();
    // Insert sample HTML content
    builder.InsertHtml("<p>Hello World</p>");
    doc.NodeChangingCallback = null;

    builder.InsertHtml("<p>Some Test Text</p>");


    doc.Save(@"Out.docx");
}



public class HandleNodeChanging_FontChanger : INodeChangingCallback
{
    // Implement the NodeInserted handler to set default font settings for every Run node inserted into the Document
    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeInserted(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {

        // Change the font of inserted text contained in the Run nodes.
        if (args.Node.NodeType == NodeType.Run)
        {

            Run run = (Run)args.Node;
            Console.WriteLine(run.Text);
            run.Font.StyleName = "Intense Emphasis";
            // Aspose.Words.Font font = ((Run)args.Node).Font;
            // font.Size = 24;
            // font.Name = "Arial";
        }
    }

    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeInserting(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeRemoved(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeRemoving(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}
```

I work with Aspose as developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, got much more styling options with your solution. Also, is there any good aspose api reference except [this](https://apireference.aspose.com/) because it doesn't have much information. 
P.S.: It would be super good if I could ask you about several aspose features direclty, don't you mind giving me a contact email or something else?

Comment: @Max, we are sorry for the inconvenience that the API reference did not help you. We will appreciate your feedback and will improve it. Furthermore, please feel free to ask for any further assistance at stackoverflow or [Aspose forums](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a couple of hours of finding a solution I've got this to work:

```
builder.ParagraphFormat.ClearFormatting();
builder.ParagraphFormat.Style = styles["word_style1"];
builder.Writeln(post.Title);

builder.InsertParagraph();
builder.ParagraphFormat.Style = styles["word_style2"];
builder.InsertHtml(post.Annotation, true);

builder.InsertParagraph();
builder.ParagraphFormat.Style = styles["word_style3"];
builder.InsertHyperlink(post.Url, post.Url, false);
```

P.S.: I hope there are any workarounds or improvements to do ot better.